# no same numbers in array

Tags: c#

I'm making a program that accepts values into an array, but if you attempt to input the same value twice, it rejects, if the value is unique, go on.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   

        char[] charray = new char[7];

        Console.WriteLine("Enter 7 unique alphabetic characters: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < charray.Length; i++)
        {
            charray[i] = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int j = 0; j < charray.Length; j++)
            {
                if (charray[i] == charray[j])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a unique alphabetic character.");
                }
            }   
        }
        Console.WriteLine(charray);
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Please explain what the issue is - why does your code not work? Having said that, I can see you're setting `charray[i] = Convert.ToChar...` before you do the duplicate check. You should probably check for duplicates before assigning the new value.

Comment: For example, if I input "r", it says its duplicate. Then if I input "g" it says duplicate. Everything I input is "duplicate".

Comment: By the way I'll try moving the duplicate check and see if it works

Answer (score 3):

you're comparing every element in your array with what you just assigned to an element in your array, so of course you'll always find a duplicate... with the item you just entered.

What you actually want is:

```
void Main()
{
    char[] charray = new char[7];

    Console.WriteLine("Enter 7 unique alphabetic characters: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < charray.Length; i++)
    {
        var x = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
        if (charray.Contains(x))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a unique alphabetic character.");
            i--;
        }
        else
        {
            charray[i] = x;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(charray);
}
```

Comment: So this is the only way to do it? I thought I was on the right track with my nest for loops and if statement

Comment: @Gravy_Train Both are essentially the same, `Contains` is simply more succinct. You can replace the `if (charray.Contains(x))` with your inner loop and if - the important changes here is the `i--` and moving the assignment *after* the check

Comment: Makes sense, however I wasn't trying to use Linq. I'm trying to stay away from it until I have more of an understanding of the fundamentals. Thanks by the way

Answer (score 0):

By the way this approach is quite slow specially if you extend your array, 7 is fine but the level of optimization is very poor, you might want to look at concept of ***Hash map***. And like the others said, since you first insert the input inside your array, the for will always find your input inside and return duplicated, you might want to check the duplication before insertion operation.

Comment: I am still a beginner, please understand.

Comment: I understand and that is why I recommended you to study such concept, so you will gradually improve. @Phil answer is correct and will work for you right away.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose the following implementation:

```
char[] charArray = new char[7];
Console.WriteLine("Enter {0} unique alphabetic characters: ", charArray.Length);

int i = 0;
while (i < charArray.Length)
{
    char inputChar = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
    Console.WriteLine();

    if (charArray.Contains(inputChar))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a unique alphabetic character.");
    }
    else
    {
        charArray[i] = inputChar;
        ++i;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(charArray);
```